# Rails: Order found objects with a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

```
Class User

has_many_belongs_to_many :books

end

Class Book

has_many_belongs_to_many :users

end
```

I'm trying to create a list of books and order them by the number of users they have:

```
Book.find(:all,:conditions => ['title LIKE ?', "%#{params[:autocomplete]}%"],
:limit => 5, :include => :users, :order => "users.count DESC")
```

Unfortunately, this throws an error telling me that there is no users column:

```
<pre>Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'users.count' in 'order clause': SELECT  `books`.*
FROM `books`  WHERE (title LIKE '%pop%') ORDER BY users DESC LIMIT 5</pre>
```

If I remove "count," I still get an error saying that it Mysql can't find "users." Any idea how to get this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `users.count DESC`, rails will try to find the column `users.count`. You need to remove the `count` and refer to the `user.id` instead.

Try to change the `:order => "users.count DESC"` for `:order => "COUNT(users.id) DESC"`.

I cannot test it now, but I believe it should solve the problem...

**EDIT** - Try the new way to query (Rails 3). Should be something like the below:

```
Book.where('title LIKE ?', "%#{params[:autocomplete]}%").includes(:users).order(COUNT(users.id) DESC").limit(5)
```

Comment: This seems like a step in the right direction. Mysql no longer throws an error, but this solution doesn't quiet work either. Instead of returning five items, it only returns one. This one isn't necessarily the item with the largest number of users, either. I'll keep exploring the COUNT function now that I know about it, and if I find an answer I'll update.

Comment: I am on Rails 3, though I haven't heard of the new way.

Comment: A good railscast about it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3?view=asciicast

Comment: Great railscast, as usual. The code now works great. It reads: Book.where('title LIKE ?', "%#{params[:autocomplete]}%").includes(:users).order("users.id desc").limit(5)